Job suffering for the misdeeds of his ancestors
The Torah introduces the idea of intergenerational punishment (Ex 20.5): "For I, your God YHWH, am an impassioned God, visiting the guilt of the parents upon the children, upon the third and upon the fourth generations of those who reject Me."
Moreover, it is unanimously accepted (in Judaism) that suffering as an inherent condition of the human race, stems from Adam's original sin. So, presumably, all generations must have known to attribute their sorrows to their ancestors' misdeeds.
The Book of Job contrasts different explanations for Job's suffering (surprisingly nobody reveals to him the true cause which was merely a bet between God and Satan): Divine Testing, Retributive Justice, Mystery of Suffering, and God's Sovereignty.
We observe that Job attempts to atone for the possible sins of his children by bringing sacrifices, implying that he's aware of some intergenerational influence.
However, nobody in the book suggests that he may simply pay for his forebears being idolaters which is more than reasonable.
Why is this option not on the table?

There is a Rabbeinu Bachaya that explains how the "visiting the punishment on the children to the third and fourth generation" is actually known as a "midda rachamim" - one of Hashem's 13 attributes of mercy. Therefore, we need to understand what is merciful about it, because it comes across as justice (and at first glance, might even seem unjust, chas veshalom)
So, the explanation is this. A person who sins and deserves to be cut off is not cut off. Instead, Hashem exercises patience and mercy, and allows his children to atone for him. If his children continue to sin, Hashem still doesn't cut off the family line, but waits another generation, perhaps up to four. This can only go on so long, and eventually if there is no sign of teshuva from this branch, it will be cut off.
So, we can see, this act of mercy isn't about getting transferred punishments from our ancestors. Rather, it is that we are influenced by their ways, and we get a chance to do teshuva for the whole branch by overcoming these ways (and perhaps even tested by Hashem as part of the rectification process - true teshuva, as Rambam teaches, is achieved when we are tested again and pass, and perhaps this is part of what is being "visited" upon the children).
Job was a Tzaddik, and therefore, he had already "started fresh". Any sins of his ancestors will have been atoned for by him, and therefore he doesn't need to be tested for their sake. This story is actually about the righteous suffering, rather than sinners suffering.

Wait, isn't being merciful to the sinner cruelty and injustice toward his descendants? You suddenly inserted "tested" and that spoils everything. Let's stay with the punishment, which is agreeably collective, not personal (we see that this is the general Torah view on reward and punishment). I don't see how you arrived at the conclusion in the last paragraph that he started fresh - we saw tons of Tzaddikim perishing in the holocaust, and suffering for the sins of their forerunners is the defaultive apologetics. But thanks for the reply!

@AlBerko please don't jump so quickly - you are misunderstanding me. Ask a question or 2. I said in the final sentence that there is a type of suffering that is not related to punishment or tests (that applies to sinners), it's a separate topic called "the suffering of the righteous". There was a big machlokes between the Lubavitcher Rebbe and Rav Shach, btw, about the purpose of the holocaust. I hold by the Lubavitcher Rebbe's arguments - it was NOT a punishment, fyi.

OK, sorry. You somehow understood that Job was a sort of a Tzaddik with a clean sheet. How? 2. There ARE additional explanations, but the ancestral sin AFAIK is not denied by anyone. 3. Suffering <> punishment. Please explain.


Job 1:1, 2. See Targum on your pasuk Ex 20.5 (and doesn't matter if there are alternative explanations, I am quoting my sources), 3. If Job is blameless, and is suffering, we can't call it punishment. How that works is its own question :)


"its own question" which Moshe Rabbeinu wrote a very long book to try to answer, so anyone who claims to answer it in less is either getting it wrong or grossly oversimplifying

@Heshy and even to this day, even our "loftiest" sources from the Kabbalah, still say this is something we can't understand.
